# Button to increment 1 value on first and second range - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want button to increment 1 value to first and second range and button decrement  1 value on first and second range

my code:

```js
function run(){
  var one = document.getElementById("range1").value;
  document.getElementById('out1').value=one; 
   var two = document.getElementById("range2").value;
  document.getElementById('out2').value=two; 
  }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range1" step="1" value="20" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)"  id="range1"/>
 <output id="out1">20</output>

<input type="range" name="range2" step="1" value="37" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)"  id="range2"/>
<output id="out2">37</output>
<br>
<button>+</button><button>-</button><br><br><br>
<h2>+ :increment 1 value on both of them</h2>
<h2>- :decrement 1 value on both of them</h2>
and live change
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function run(){
   var one = document.getElementById("range1").value;
   document.getElementById('out1').value=one; 
   var two = document.getElementById("range2").value;
   document.getElementById('out2').value=two; 
  }
function plus(){
   document.getElementById("range1").value++;
   document.getElementById("range2").value++;
   run();
}
function minus(){
   document.getElementById("range1").value--;
   document.getElementById("range2").value--;
   run();
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range1" step="1" value="20" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)"  id="range1"/>
 <output id="out1">20</output>

<input type="range" name="range2" step="1" value="37" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)"  id="range2"/>
<output id="out2">37</output>
<br>
<button onclick="plus()">+</button><button onclick="minus()">-</button><br><br><br>
<h2>+ :increment 1 value on both of them</h2>
<h2>- :decrement 1 value on both of them</h2>
and live change
```

- Created two functions(and assigned them to the `onclick` events of the buttons)
- Both either add 1 or substract 1 (`++` and `--` are shorthand for `+=1` and `-=1`)
- Both functions call `run()` in order to refresh the values of output tags.

More info:

`++`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment

`--`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Subtraction_assignment

Comment: best answer but when i put html code in form and when i clicked the page is reloade

Comment: Try setting the buttons with `type="button"` in the HTML. This will prevent the default action of the button, which is `submit` the form (which makes the page reload)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Add a click event to the buttons and increment or decrement the vale as necessary.

```js
function run() {
  var one = document.getElementById("range1").value;
  document.getElementById('out1').value = one;
  var two = document.getElementById("range2").value;
  document.getElementById('out2').value = two;
}

function setNewValue(val) {
  var r1 = document.getElementById("range1");
  r1val = parseInt(r1.value) + val;
  if (r1val >= 0 && r1val <= 100) {
    r1.value = r1val;
    document.getElementById('out1').value = r1val;
  }

  var r2 = document.getElementById("range2");
  r2val = parseInt(r2.value) + val;
  if (r2val >= 0 && r2val <= 100) {
    r2.value = r2val;
    document.getElementById('out2').value = r2val;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range1" step="1" value="20" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)" id="range1" />
<output id="out1">20</output>

<input type="range" name="range2" step="1" value="37" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)" id="range2" />
<output id="out2">37</output>
<br>
<button onclick="setNewValue(1)">+</button>
<button onclick="setNewValue(-1)">-</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h2>+ :increment 1 value on both of them</h2>
<h2>- :decrement 1 value on both of them</h2>
and live change
```

Comment: that also great but i want simple code like first answer .. Maybe someone else will benefit from your answer I needed, and I'm in another time

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a simple solution with jQuery:

```js
$('#more').click(function() {
  $('#range1').val(parseInt($('#range1').val())+1);
  $('#out1').text($('#range1').val());
  $('#range2').val(parseInt($('#range2').val())+1);
  $('#out2').text($('#range2').val());
});

$('#less').click(function() {
  $('#range1').val(parseInt($('#range1').val())-1);
  $('#out1').text($('#range1').val())
  $('#range2').val(parseInt($('#range2').val())-1);
  $('#out2').text($('#range2').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" name="range1" step="1" value="20" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)" id="range1" />
<output id="out1">20</output>

<input type="range" name="range2" step="1" value="37" min="0" max="100" oninput="run(this.value)" id="range2" />
<output id="out2">37</output>
<br>
<button id="more">+</button>
<button id="less">-</button>
<br>
<h2>+ :increment 1 value on both of them</h2>
<h2>- :decrement 1 value on both of them</h2>
and live change
```

Comment: that also great but i want simple code like first answer .. Maybe someone else will benefit from your answer I needed, and I'm in another time